# Open Private/Incognito Window with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, incognito-mode

I am trying to find a simple javascript to open a new private/incognito window. I have seen

`chrome.windows.create({url: "about:blank", type: "popup", incognito: true});`

and

`browser.windows.create({url: "about:blank", type: "popup", incognito: true});`

But I understand that this may only work with an extension or from an app. Can someone confirm that this cannot be done from a standard web page viewed in a modern browser (Chrome and Firefox)

Comment: Is there something preventing you from throwing a quick web page together and trying this yourself?

Comment: I did and I get the following error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined

Comment: You simply can't, the api you reference is specific for extensions.

Comment: Is there anything else I might consider to make it work or give up?

Comment: @vanreus I'm fairly certain it's not possible at all. It could be abused to match an incognito session to a regular session, which would defeat the purpose of using incognito.

Comment: @Ivar That is disappointing. Thanks for the comment.